# "Cannot resolve symbol `Request`" error for facebook Graph API

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api, android-studio, facebook-android-sdk

I include latest facebook SDK `4.0.1`into the Android Studio project. I want to do basic Graph API call as listed on [Graph API reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3)

```
/* make the API call */
new Request(
    session,
    "/me",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

But i am unable to import `Request` class, i am getting error `Cannot resolve symbol`Request``.

How to resolve this problem? Do i need to import some other library to use Graph API?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Request class has been renamed to GraphRequest.

Answer (score 6):

Other than `Request` is changed to `GraphRequest`, `Response` is changed to `GraphResponse` and now instead of passing `session`, pass `AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken or accessToken` in the constructor. So your query will be like this:

```
  GraphRequestAsyncTask graphRequest = new GraphRequest(
                    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                    "/{user-id}/",
                    null,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
        /* handle the result */
                        }
                    }
            ).executeAsync();
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks - i was looking for the new code for SDK 4. It appeared that Facebook has not updated their guides for SDK 4 and is using old examples. I wish they updated all their examples before realising SDK 4. +1

Comment: Really helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As @Gokhan explained, the class is called *GraphRequest* now.

Facebook SDK 4.x is a major update over 3.x with many changes, you should check out Facebook's [upgrading guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/upgrading-4.x).